# eclipse custom editor comes up blank

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing a custom editor for eclipse, it works fine when I run it as an eclipse application, but when I install it through an update site, the editor has no content when opened. How do I fix this?

[image: eclipse screenshot]

Source code for plugin, feature, and update-site: https://github.com/programmerjake/peg_parser_generator-eclipse commit [4c01fba773ea2cd60ab0efd08fae1331b18b62bc](https://github.com/programmerjake/peg_parser_generator-eclipse/tree/4c01fba773ea2cd60ab0efd08fae1331b18b62bc)

update site url: http://programmerjake.tk/peg_parser_generator-eclipse/tk.programmerjake.peg_parser_generator.update_site/ version 0.1.1.5

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the plugin built didn't contain the actual editor classes, because the jvm version was set to 1.6 but the source code contains version 1.7 features.